# WPF Listbox Collection custom sort

Tags: wpf, sorting, listbox, compare, collectionview

I have a listbox

```
DropPrice
MyPrice
Price1
Price2
```

I want to sort it like this

```
Price1
Price2
DropPrice
MyPrice
```

I mean, if there's an item that starts with the sequence "price", it gets priority, else the smallest string should get the priority.

My source code:

```
var lcv = (ListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_itemsSource));
var customSort = new PrioritySorting("price");
lcv.CustomSort = customSort;

internal class PrioritySorting : IComparer
    {
        private string _text;
        public PrioritySorting(string text)
        {
            _text = text;
        }

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
           //my sorting code here

        }
    }
```

How can i write compare method. I know, that it can return 1,0 or -1. How can i set priorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to check if it starts with "price".

Note that I don't think that `ToString()` is appropriate; you should rather implement `IComparer<T>` and strongly type your objects in your listbox.

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    // test for equality
    if (x.ToString() == y.ToString())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // if x is "price" but not y, x goes above
    if (x.ToString().StartsWith("Price") && !y.ToString().StartsWith("Price"))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // if y is "price" but not x, y goes above
    if (!x.ToString().StartsWith("Price") && y.ToString().StartsWith("Price"))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // otherwise, compare normally (this way PriceXXX are also compared among themselves)
    return string.Compare(x.ToString(), y.ToString());
}
```

Comment: looks working, but we need to swap 1 and -1 positions

Comment: I wasn't very sure which one would go where... Fixed, thanks.

Comment: also we can't check string>string (x > y), what if we use String.compare(x,y)

Comment: Yes, of course. But as I said, I don't think using ToString() is a good idea (I'm not even sure it will work with your objects). You should strongly-type your list items, and use properties on these items to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code snippet for IComparer.

```
private class sortYearAscendingHelper : IComparer
{
   int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
   {
      car c1=(car)a;
      car c2=(car)b;
      if (c1.year > c2.year)
         return 1;
      if (c1.year < c2.year)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
   }
}
```

This is more specific to your Question

```
 internal class PrioritySorting : IComparer
    {
        private string _text;
        public PrioritySorting(string text)
        {
            _text = text;
        }

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            var str1 = x as string;
            var str2 = y as string;

            if (str1.StartsWith("price") )
            {
                if (str2.StartsWith("price"))
                    return 0;
                return 1;
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i know, but if there's an item that starts with the given sequence, i need to display that items first

Comment: That wouldn't be right... This way you're only separating items that start with "price" and items that don't. He want them to be sorted also. That means that if both items start with "price", or both don't, you should the compare them normally and return the result of that comparation.